# How to use a file to write input and the date and time

Tags: python

I am trying to learn how to use a while loop that records every incorrect try, includes the time and date and a reason why. The output should also show the incorrect/weak attempts of the file.

```
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 14
PASSWORD_LOG_FILE = "password_log_your_name.txt"
password = input("Enter your password: ")
password_length = len(password)


while password_length >= MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH and password_length <= MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:

    PASSWORD_LOG_FILE = open("password_log_your_name.txt", "a")

    PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write(password)
    PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write("\n")

    import datetime

    my_date = datetime.datetime.today()

    print(str(datetime.datetime.today()))
    todays_date = my_date.strftime('%A %B %d, %Y')

    print(f"Date: {todays_date:s}\n")

    PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.close()

    if password.isalpha():
        print("Your password is weak! It only contains letters.")
    elif password.isnumeric():
        print("Your password is weak! It only contains numbers.")
    else:
        print("Your password is strong! It contains letters and numbers.")
    break
```

I'm not sure how the sequence should go? I know I need to use the datetime to record the time for when they tried a attempt and use .write to write in the file. I think anyway but I am confused as to how to combine everything.

Comment: Consider file handling using `with` instead

Comment: Did you hear what happened in Facebook? Avoid doing this `PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write(password)`!

Comment: Could you post a sample of your desired output?

Comment: `todays_date = my_date.strftime('%A %B %d, %Y')` Whaa?

Comment: Do you want to keep all the attempts in the file? Be it weak or strong? or only the strong ones?

Comment: incorrect/weak attempts

Comment: @user3699543 see the answer I posted below?

Comment: Yeah I did. Really appreciate it. Seems a bit more than what I have learnt though lol I think the whole point was to try and add on from what I learnt. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you need to store all the attempts, be it `week` or `strong`, I would suggest using a `while True` and with the following sequence:

```
import datetime
ps_file = "list.txt"

while True:
    p_inp = input("Enter your password OR Press N to quit")
    if p_inp.lower() == 'n':
        exit()
    with open(ps_file, 'a+') as fileObj:
        if p_inp.isalpha():
            print("Your password is weak! It only contains letters.")
            p_strength = "weak"
        elif p_inp.isnumeric():
            print("Your password is weak! It only contains numbers.")
            p_strength = "weak"
        else:
            print("Your password is strong! It contains letters and numbers.")
            p_strength = "strong"

        fileObj.write("Date: {}".format(datetime.datetime.today()) + "\n")
        fileObj.write("Password: {}".format(p_inp + "\n"))
        fileObj.write("Password strength: {}".format(p_strength) + "\n")
```

**OUTPUT** (list.txt):

```
Date: 2019-03-27 11:41:10.107696
Password: weekattempt
Password strength: weak
Date: 2019-03-27 11:41:14.388402
Password: strongattempt1
Password strength: strong
Date: 2019-03-27 11:41:26.812254
Password: strongatempt2
Password strength: strong
```

**EDIT**:

It would be even better if you use a separate functions for password validation and file writing:

```
import datetime

ps_week = "WEEK"
ps_strong = "STRONG"

ps_week_a = "Your password is weak! It only contains letters."
ps_week_b = "Your password is weak! It only contains number."
ps_strong_a = "Your password is strong! It contains letters and numbers."


def writeTofile(fileObj, p_strength, p_text):
    fileObj.write("Date: {}".format(datetime.datetime.today()) + "\n")
    fileObj.write("Password: {}".format(p_inp + "\n"))
    fileObj.write("Password strength: {}".format(p_strength) + "\n")
    fileObj.write("Prompt: {}".format(p_text) + "\n")

def p_validate(p_inp, fileObj):
    if p_inp.isalpha():
        writeTofile(fileObj, ps_week, ps_week_a)
    elif p_inp.isnumeric():
        writeTofile(fileObj, ps_week, ps_week_b)
    else:
        writeTofile(fileObj, ps_strong, ps_strong_a)

while True:
    p_inp = input("Enter your password OR Press N to quit")
    if p_inp.lower() == 'n':
        exit()
    with open('list.txt', 'a+') as fileObj:
        p_validate(p_inp, fileObj)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Date: 2019-03-27 11:51:36.512665
Password: weakweak
Password strength: WEAK
Prompt: Your password is weak! It only contains letters.
Date: 2019-03-27 11:51:55.704586
Password: strongatttempt1
Password strength: STRONG
Prompt: Your password is strong! It contains letters and numbers.
Date: 2019-03-27 11:52:50.609155
Password: strongattempt2
Password strength: STRONG
Prompt: Your password is strong! It contains letters and numbers.
```

Comment: My only recommendation on top of the general structure (because it doesn't alter the functionality of what you are looking for) is to actually do all your password validations in a separate function and let the function return its verdict to the caller who them promptly writes it to a file.
What this does is that if you have a lot more complex rules thereby expanding the if-else loops, then you don't have to worry about where to close the file handle or re-open, etc.

Comment: @perennial_noob Indeed could be the case, I separated all the function in my edit. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of why would you plan to do any thing this way. But as per your question, this should be the sequence. You might would want to use context handling using `with open('filename','a') as PASSWORD_LOG_FILE:` to do file handling stuff. This is just to demonstrate a sequence of doing what you are trying to do. Tried to use most of your code.

```
import datetime

MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 14
PASSWORD_LOG_FILE = "password_log_your_name.txt"
password = input("Enter your password: ")
password_length = len(password)


if password_length >= MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH and password_length <= MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
    if password.isalpha():
        print("Your password is weak! It only contains letters.")
    elif password.isnumeric():
        print("Your password is weak! It only contains numbers.")
    else:
        print("Your password is strong! It contains letters and numbers.")
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE = open("password_log_your_name.txt", "a")
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write(password)
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write("\n")
        my_date = datetime.datetime.today()
        print(str(datetime.datetime.today()))
        todays_date = my_date.strftime('%A %B %d, %Y')
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write(todays_date)
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write("\n")
        print(f"Date: {todays_date:s}\n")
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.close()
```

Comment: The OP actually wants to record all incorrect/weak attempts. This will record the strong attempts only displaying on the terminal the weak ones.

Comment: Oh, Sorry din see the expected output then.

Comment: Is there way to change the code so it does record the weak/incorrect ones?